# MVC Child Master page with Razor

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have an old MVC2 project that I gradulately convert to MVC 5, with Razor.

As the razor views with ASP Master Pages is not possible, I decided to duplicate the `Site.Master` into `_Layout.cshtml`.

Everything is OK But there is a problem, however.

I have an other Master page, `TwoColumnsLayout.Master`, a kind of "child" master page, that begins like this:

```
<%@ Master MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage" %>

<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="MetaContent" runat="server">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MetaContent" runat="server" />
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server" />
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <div class="breadcrumbs">
    ...
```

How is possible to convert and use this one with the Razor engine?

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/30/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts-and-sections-with-razor.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

utilize `@{ Layout = ""; }` feature.

For Example:

**~/Views/Shared/_LayoutMain.cshtml**:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href="..." rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <!-- header markup -->
    @RenderBody()
    <!-- footer markup -->
</body>
</html>
```

**~/Views/Shared/_LayoutChild.cshtml**:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutMain.cshtml";
}
<!-- Child Layout content -->
<div>
    @RenderBody()
</div>
```

**~/Views/MyPage/_SomeViewPage.cshtml**:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutChild.cshtml";
}

<div>
    @RenderBody()
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use nested layout templates instead.

Create another layout `_TwoColumnsLayout.cshtml` with the following:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

//Nested specific markup ...

@RenderBody()
```

Then in your view specify your new nested template as follows:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Shared/_TwoColumnsLayout.cshtml.cshtml";
}
```