# ASP.NET MVC 5 how to reference a Master Page in a different viewer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

i have a master page with flat ui css, i want to reference the master page in an MVC view, my viewers use pure HTMl

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
```

when i run my project, it complains about the first line of code
    <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master"%>

How to do this in MVC 5 ASP.Net

Comment: this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22506755/asp-child-master-page-with-razor/22507126#22507126